# prettyPhoto Works on Wordpress Post but Not Page

Tags: jquery, wordpress, prettyphoto

Link (removed) should open with prettyPhoto instead of a standard href link.

I copy and paste the exact code into a wordpress post and its prettyPhoto works.

The jquery and prettyPhoto scripts are included both times, along with the css and the prettyPhoto javascript. No idea what's going on.

Comment: there is another error of javascript of superfish() function solve that first becoz it might be stopping your prettyphoto code to execute

Comment: That could be it as this doesn't happen on a standard page: TypeError: jQuery(...).superfish is not a function

Haven't been able to figure out how to fix the function though. How to fix?

Comment: Turns out I was including another jquery file after the superfish jquery. This then broke the prettyPhoto script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your wordress site there is issue regarding superfish() javascript function

please find on that

jQuery(document).ready(function()

there is a problem with $test = jQuery.noConflict();

now replace jQuery to $test

please solve this with conflict jquery.